# Issues rendering background image in a visual force page into a word document

Tags: visualforce, css, html

I'm having a couple of issues rendering a visual force page into a word document. The output I'm getting is in the image below. And what I'm trying to achieve is to have the table on the second page to be rendered on top of the image on the first page. However nothing I've tried to far seems to be working

[image]

The markup looks like this

```
<div class="body">

            <div class = "watermark">     
                   <!---- <apex:image value="{!URLFOR($Resource.Example)}" height="50%" width="100%"/> ---->
                   <!---- <apex:image value="{!URLFOR($Resource.Example)}" width="100%" height="100%" /> ---->
                   <!---- <img src="https://example--c.documentforce.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=0154J000000Jhlr&oid=00D4J000000D3J8&lastMod=1582018831000" height="30%" width="30%"/> ---->
                   <!---- <img src="https://example--c.documentforce.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=0154J000000cXlf&oid=00D4J000000D3J8&lastMod=1559560097000" height="100%" width="100%"/> ---->
                   <!-- <apex:image url="https://example--c.documentforce.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=0154J000000cXlf&oid=00D4J000000D3J8&lastMod=1559560097000" width="100%" height="100%" /> -->
           </div>

            <table style="width:100%; background-color: #9CDBCD">
              <tr>        
                  <td class="tablebox">{! Opportunity.Account.Name} <br/><br/>
                      {! Opportunity.Name } <br/>    
                  </td>
                  <td class="tablebox2">&nbsp;&nbsp;{! Opportunity.Type} <br/>
                      &nbsp;&nbsp;{! Opportunity.Owner.Title} <br/>
                      &nbsp;&nbsp;{! Opportunity.Owner.FirstName} {! Opportunity.Owner.LastName} <br/>
                      &nbsp;&nbsp;Date &nbsp;<apex:outputText value="{0,date,dd'.'MM'.'yyyy}"><apex:param value="{! Opportunity.Estimate_date__c }" /></apex:outputText> <br/>

                  </td>    
              </tr>   
               </table>
        <div class = "watermark">     
                    <!-- <apex:image value="https://example--c.visualforce.com/resource/1581689042000/Test1?" height="50%" width="100%"/> -->
                    <!-- <img src="https://example--c.documentforce.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=0154J000000Jhlw&oid=00D4J000000D3J8&lastMod=1582018900000"  style="height: 50px; width: 50px;"/> -->
            </div>

    </div>
```

And the CSS looks like this

```
.watermark {
                position: absolute;
                opacity: 0.25;
                font-size: 3em;
                width: 100%;
                text-align: center;
                z-index: 1000;

                 background-image: url("https://example-sites.secure.force.com/resources/resource/1559208707000/");
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                background-attachment: fixed;
                background-size: cover;     
            }
```

Any ideas on how this could be resolved, or if it is even possible?
Thanks!